# PHP: Detecting a particular sequence of elements in an array

Tags: php, arrays, sequence

How do I detect if a certan sequence of elements is present in an array? E.g. if I have the arrays and needle

```
$needle = array(1,1);
$haystack1 = array(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0);
$haystack2 = array(0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1);
```

How does one detect if the subset $needle is present in e.g. $haystack1? This method should return TRUE for $haystack1 and FALSE for $haystack2.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Are your arrays always just single-digit numeric values?

Comment: In my case, yes. Actually they'll always be boolean 1's and 0's as they represent target and non-target trials in a cognitive task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join the arrays, and check for the strpos of the needle.

```
if ( strpos( join($haystack1), join($needle) ) >= 0 ) {
    echo "Items found";
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/F13DLWOI

**Warning**

This will not work for complicated items like objects or arrays within the haystack array. This method is best used with itesm like numbers and strings.

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! Very nice and simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

If they're always a single digit/character then you can convert all elements to strings, join by `''`, and use the regex or string functions to search.

Comment: Thank you, Ignacio. I guess that's what Jonathan also proposed with code.

Answer (score 3):

**For the specific case where no array element is a prefix of any other element** (when both are converted to strings) then the already posted answers will work fine and probably be pretty fast.

Here's an approach that will work correctly in the general case:

```
function subarray_exists(array $needle, array $haystack) {
    if (count($needle) > count($haystack)) {
        return false;
    }

    $needle = array_values($needle);
    $iterations = count($haystack) - count($needle) + 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
        if (array_slice($haystack, $i, count($needle)) == $needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[**See it in action**](http://ideone.com/Cp58w).

*Disclaimer: There are ways to write this function that I expect will make it execute much faster when you are searching huge haystacks, but for a first approach simple is good.*

Comment: Thank you for putting this code here for the record, Jon. I was thinking of something like this too in the first place, but figured that there would be more clever solutions to my single-digits case.